No input-method activated but still prefix behaviour
When I'm programming, I don't want any 'input-method' activated.
However, since a few days, I can't e.g. type " anymore without hitting <space> afterwards. More precisely (taking up @phils comments):
What happens when I type

I type " -> Nothing is displayed.
I type <space> -> the character " appears.

Variant: Type " and then a -> ä
The same happens in the minibuffer.
What happens when C-h k "
Nothing. It's waiting for the next keystroke. When I type again <space>
Help shows
" runs the command self-insert-command (found in global-map), which is
an interactive built-in function in ‘C source code’.

It is bound to many ordinary text characters.

   (self-insert-command N &optional C)

...

What happens when " C-h
In the minibuffer this message appears: C-ḧ is undefined
input method
C-h I for current choice displays: No input method is activated
term/shell/etc
In my underlying shell typing " works (i.e. I get a double quote).
Addendum (2): Input works fine without window: emacs -nw is fine.
What am I missing?
Additional info being maybe of interest:
I have a wsl-2.0 setup (on Windows 10) with Ubuntu-22.04 LTS and running on MobaXterm.
I'm using GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.33, cairo version 1.16.0)
My windows keyboard is ENG-US.

(Upvoted for including useful details).  When you say "can't e.g. type " anymore without hitting  afterwards", what actually happens when you type "?  What do you see in the buffer and/or the minibuffer/echo area?  What does C-h k " say?  If it's acting as a prefix binding, does " C-h show you anything?

In the meantime I found out that something was wrong with the X/Gtk/Windowing system.
Closing my MobaXterm/Ubuntu sessions and starting up again, the issue was gone.
I've checked the keystrokes with xev and noticed that after the restart it shows
these key events for "":
KeyPress event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x200001,
    root 0xf3, subw 0x0, time 284564484, (69,99), root:(2125,258),
    state 0x0, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x200001,
    root 0xf3, subw 0x0, time 284564906, (69,99), root:(2125,258),
    state 0x1, keycode 48 (keysym 0x22, quotedbl), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (22) """
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (22) """
    XFilterEvent returns: False

During the issue, I'm sure (but haven't retained the log statements) I saw
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x200001,
    root 0xf3, subw 0x0, time 284564906, (69,99), root:(2125,258),
    state 0x1, keycode 48 (keysym 0x22, quotedbl), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (22) "¨"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (22) "¨"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Therefore, I assume it's not an emacs issue, but something with the windowing system
got corrupted...
Anyways, thank you again phils for your debugging hints!
